# I wasn't able to install the ubuntu OS using the "erase disk" option

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I was fully ready to install ubuntu as my main OS but for some reason Linux lost another loser who couldn't figure out an I/O error to windows. I tried installing 20.04, 22.04, mint, and installed Ubuntu 22.04 about three times.

I already had ubuntu on a 30 GB partition on my Dell N-5010 laptop, but I wanted to erase my hard drive and install Ubuntu as the only OS on my laptop. So I used the "erase disk" option to have Ubuntu partition my hard disk and install the OS. But about 73% into the installation process I received an Inpit/Output error. Apparently there was something wrong with my Flash Drive or my Hard Disk. So I booted the USB for BIOS systems. I used other distros (I heard that Mint was smoother on older laptops) but I got the same error.

I assume that there is a problem with the Linux set-up or some other low level program that fails to install on my Hard Drive. I even tried to partition the Disk my self and install it on a large portion of the disk (a 300 GB partition) but I failed again.

Is it possible that This OS's are not designed to handle big partitions? Because that is exactly what I want. I hate double boots and I absolutely abhor having 40 gigs on my main OS. I watch lectures and movies and use upwards of 120 GBs when studying with my laptop. So unless there is a way for me to install Ubuntu as the main OS on my laptop, there is no use in having another pesky double boot that just renders 20% of my Hard Disk useless.

meanwhile windows 10 which is supposedly harder on on old systems installed like a breeze. The installation was very slow, but I am told that that's how breezes blow. Linux on the other hand (all the different distros and versions) booted and installed like typhons and crashed like typhons. I assume that I can do a double boot now, but that is not what I do.

My device: *Dell N5010 laptop Core i3, 8 GiB RAM, 320 GiB hard disk.*

The distros that I tried: *Ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 ; Pop! OS 22.04 LTS , Mint OS 20.3 all of them 64 bit.*

Methods of making bootable USB: **I used Ubuntu's native device but when my hard drive was fried I used Rufus. used both availible schemes in Rufus.**

Comment: From your description; the I/O error was on your drive thus you should check your hardware. Ubuntu checks the media on boot; so installation problems are more often related to the hardware itself (you'll get CD errors if it's your installation media; showing as *squashfs* errors; unable to read data - not IO).  Re-read the error(s) and consider it; and validate the SMART issue.  This is also a Ubuntu Q&A site & doesn't support Linux Mint, Pop OS or non-Ubuntu OSes.  FYI:  The OS can handle partitions up to 1024PB; you mention on GB  (*two levels below PB*)

Comment: Being able to install Windows does not mean that it will work well. I would not trust the hard drive anymore, you might get issues later on or lose data. Run `chkdisk` or similar to check the hard drive for errors. The size of your hard drive is surely not the issue!

Comment: Looks like first gen i-series chip and from 2011. That was about the time vendors started change from BIOS/MBR to UEFI/gpt. Back then I used gpt partitioning with BIOS, but needed a bios_grub partition for grub to work. So is system early UEFI (which may have bugs)? And have you updated to latest available UEFI/BIOS that Dell has? You can use larger / of your 320GB, but most suggest smaller / of 30 to 40GB and rest as /home or as data partition.  Then system still looks like entire 320GB used. What graphics card/chip? With old systems that can be an issue.